# XML text processing

Tags: java, xml, text-processing

In my complex XML stored already just as String I have to make some text/xml-processing. The goal is to find the beginning index of some **given** node. Apart node (**Node/Element class reference**) I have also **information about nesting**: array of integers saying in which child should I step into. E.g. for array:

```
2 1 0
```

And given tree

```
root
  |--root-child0
  |--root-child1
  |--root-child2
       |--root-child2-child0
       |--root-child2-child1
                   |--root-child2-child1-child0
```

I am searching **root-child2-child1-child0**

Is there any *clean* possibility to find such item. Just string finding (*String.indexOf()*) isn't enough - in my XML file there are many identical tags. Besides this searching there is also one additional difficulty - between some parent and children tags can exist one additional (*Collection*) tag. (E.g. the only child of root-child2 could be *Collection* and root-child2-child0 and root-child2-child1 are children of this *Collection*)

--edit

If this could help - I could also, besides mentioned nesting information, have node names corresponding to nodes on path to node I'm searching.

--edit 2

With such xml file

```
<catalog>
    <book id="bk101">
        <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
        <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
        <genre>Computer</genre>
    </book>
    <book id="bk102">
        <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
        <title>Midnight Rain</title>
        <genre>Fantasy</genre>
        <price>5.95</price>
    </book>
</catalog>
```

Let's assume **I have Node object reference** to price tag with value 5.95. Additionaly I have information about nesting:

```
1  3
```

saying that it is second (numeration from 0) book in catalog and forth tag in this book (id="bk102").

What I want is to get something like

```
xmlRawBody.indexOf("<price>5.95</price>").
```

Why can't I use this simple method? Because there is possibility that the same tag will be present in some other place. I have to use mentioned, additional nesting information.

Comment: Just wondering why do you want to know the position of a given node in the stream of character of the xml file?

Comment: As far as I know, the information about position is lost after XML parsing because they are not needed when you want to manipulate DOM objects. Most XML editors use lower level parser to handle this problem, for example, ANTLR with XML grammar.

Comment: exactly - I thought so. Thanks for ANTLR clue - I'll check it. I called this question "text processing" because of this information loose.

Answer (score 2):

What i understood is, you have the information of like `2 1 0`. From this, you are making a name of the node `root-child2-child1-chile0`.

To get the specified node like this, if the structure is fixed then you can make a xpath from that.

For example, if you have value `2 1 0`, then build xpath like `root/root-child2/root-child2-child1/root-child2-child1-child0`. You can use this xpath to fetch the specific node element.

You can make a java function, which prepares the xpath as per the given array of values accordingly. If you have more such elements, you need to find a way to identify them with xpath. Because xpath would be easy to fetch such values using `SAXParser` (If you don't want to read the whole xml, only part, then use `SAXParser`).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately this have nothing to do with node names. I have already Node object which I am looking plus I have nesting information. Last input is String XML body. What I want to get is index of '<' sign of beginning node tag.

Comment: I could also have information about node names. But I'm not sure if XPath could help me finding string index.

Comment: Just for my understanding, Do you want to split the XML in parts? Or want to read some XML chunk from it? Can you explain, so that i can relate it... thx

Comment: None. I have all the XML body. Some component of my application parsed it and gave another Node and mentioned nesting information. With these input I have to find char position and write this information to file.

Comment: From the looks of it XPATH is the tool you need, but your question is still very vague even with the little update you've put in the above comment. I suggest you try to rephrase your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Transform your array into an XPath and use the XPath engine of your choice. For instance `2 1 0` would become: `/*[3]/*[2]/*[1]`. Note that XPath positions are 1-based, so you'll have to add one to each index...

Also, the XPath engine will return you a DOM node to which you can do whatever you want. Obtaining the character or byte offset of this node is not part of the DOM and XPath specifications, so it is implementation-dependent. In most implementations you cannot because in most applications you care not.

Comment: As I said before I already **have** Node reference so obtaining it via XPath is completely unnecessary